# How to define ControllerService with expression language in Nifi

Tags: java, service, controller, expression, apache-nifi

As part of a complex model of flows that are replicated across domains, i am trying to generalise definition of custom controllerservices that are used in many processors.

Adding a ControllerService to a Processor works the same as with properties:  with the PropertyDescriptor.Builder which accepts `expressionLanguageSupported()`. However, it is not well documented how to configure this through the ui, or what additional steps need to be taken in the code of the processor that accepts said ControllerService

When i simply add the `expressionLanguageSupported(true)` method, the dropdown changes to a free input with the uuid of the configured service. 
I tried putting this uuid in a process group scoped variable called `service1`, but the validator won't accept `${service1}`

What am i doing wrong? we are using Nifi 1.6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Controller Services are not designed to work that way. You can use expression language but as you say, you will be forced to pass the controller service id.

There is a solution to this by using a lookup service. For example, the SQL processors can use [DBCPConnectionPoolLookup](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-dbcp-service-nar/1.7.1/org.apache.nifi.dbcp.DBCPConnectionPoolLookup/index.html) to dynamically pass a DBCPConnectionPool controller service to the processor.

You could use this way in your bundle.

EDIT:

You should also know that if you reference the controller service without expression language support, and make a template out of your flow, when you will deploy it, the processor will reference the controller service that was just created with your template.

Comment: i'm fine with passing the controller service id. I mainy want to avoid having to manually go over each processor to select the appropriate controllerservice each time i deploy a template.
To be specific about your answer, this id can not be provided by a scoped variable? if so, allowing expression language for controller service properties seems pretty useless?

Comment: @chaixdev It's not useless. You have to pass the controller service id, but you may pass it using the variable registry and expression language.

Comment: @chaixdev also, see the edit. I think it would be more fit to just use it as is since NiFi support referencing controller services within a template.